# Can InfoPath forms have multiple code-behind files?

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

I've recently been doing support work for few solutions built with browser-based InfoPath forms. And all of the solutions have had a large amount of customization using code-behind.

So far I've only seen one code-behind file (FormCode.cs) used for each form. Is it possible to organize (re-organize in my case) the code into multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but since the other answer was not terribly helpful, you *can* reference other classes and code in a separate strong-named assembly and include a reference to it in your project. The form's assembly may be fairly rigid, but you can always design around it. Build your other functions/classes in a separate VS project, deploy it as a SP solution, and then target your form against that.

Comment: Infopath forms are client based. It is not fixed where and how they will be deployed/published and used (from client). Have you practically succeeded in packaging multiple assemblies in one Infopath XSN template?

Comment: I am still not grasping. Code-behind is the term used for code created in MS Office VSTA as client code (except through IPFS). It is deployed from client and get from published location to run in client/filler form. How did you manage that code run on client have used assemblies on another computer, if it is not packaged in Infopath template?

Comment: The original poster is speaking to IPFS forms, not forms that will run in the InfoPath client. In IPFS, the server is running the code and you can deploy additional assemblies into the GAC for your project to reference. You may be able to reference them from /bin but I have not tried this as the GAC was generally the solution I had to go with.

Comment: Oh oh oh. Just realized this - I have worked with a client form that used external assemblies as well. You build it in a separate project and either have the output go into your InfoPath Form Template folder, or manually copy the DLL and PDB into the folder. Add it to the InfoPath Form Template solution folder, and the reference required in manifest.xsf goes like so:
`<xsf:file name="My.Assembly.Name.dll"><xsf:fileProperties><xsf:property name="fileType" type="string" value="refAssembly"></xsf:property></xsf:fileProperties></xsf:file>`

Comment: The original poster did not speak about IPFS, he wrote "browser-based" forms which is possible to open both in client/filler and in browser (the latter through IPFS), in contrast to Filler Forms openable only on client. Even more, if it is published to sharepoint location (form library, etc.) then sharepoint provides context options to choose both and I do not know the ways to get rid of sharepoint option of opening a broswer form in Infopath client

Comment: "Browser-based" generally implies IPFS. I don't think anyone could reasonably claim that a "browser-based" form is one that you host on SharePoint for people to open in Filler.

Comment: At any rate, to your question, you can't prevent it completely (the user needs read access to the location where FormServerTemplates resides and can theoretically open the template there), but from 2010 onward, you can tell the list to default to opening a browser-enabled document server-side. (List Settings -> Advanced -> 3rd option down.) You can use Jquery to remove the "Edit in Microsoft InfoPath" selection in the ECB menu. You can also use code-behind to restrict the form's operation so that it refuses to function in client mode.

Comment: Yes, I know it's been a very long time since this was answered. Both approaches suggested are valid, but I this one allows multiple IPFS or browser-based forms to reuse specific functionality. In my case, it was set of utility methods used for form validation and processing input. Deploying as a separate dll has allowed multiple forms to use the functionality without flat out copying code from form to form.

Answer (score 1):

The FormCode class is a `partial` `class`. You can add multiple code-files to organize so long as they are partial FormCode classes as well (edited per first comment).

It is possible to have embedded classes under FormCode also.

Comment: Ah, very true, forgot that bit, I was just looking at some old projects to see what made them possible. Idea still holds true, though. Partial classes will allow you multiple code-behind files.

Comment: I did not downvote but your idea will make normal and intended by design usage of Infopath form impossible, if it is possible at all

Comment: Why would it make the intended usage of InfoPath impossible? Adding additional code files to the project doesn't break anything. Using partial classes is all the same to the compiler. I knew my above idea worked no problem from past experience, and have just tested to subclass method to prove it works as well. While I will agree that if you have to put code-behind in your InfoPath forms you're likely going to have to have a bad time, it was part of the original question. It was a situation the poster inherited, not one he was designing.

Comment: +1 thanks. I managed to get more than one file too. A few files (partial classes) of the same FormCode class. Could you please extend on what did you mean under and how "to subclass method to prove it works as well" (FormCode class is sealed)?

Comment: public partial class FormCode { public class SubCls { public void SetField(XPathNavigator x, XmlNamespaceManager m) { //Set Field } } } SubCls would be the subclass I was referring to. With this setup, I can now do something like "SubCls c = new SubCls(); c.SetField();"

Comment: Thanks. Ypu could have added formatted code to your answer. This is probably not subclass (FormCode cannot be inherited/subclassed since it is a sealed class), it is embedded class

Comment: Thanks for the correction there. It helps to use the right name for things, huh? :)